# Memory Management and Performance improvement in WPF application

Tags: wpf, performance, memory

We have developed an EMR software using WPF in presentation and .NET c# libraries in business layer. WCF service call is used to communicate between server and client. The application using WPF user control for all pages and tabs in the pages. Now the problem is as the user loads pages and tabs the memory consumption increases and its not reduces until the application is stopped. Even if the user closes the old pages the memory consumption never decreases. The system goes on slowing down as the user loads more pages and close them. Some time the user closes the application and takes it again. Even that time the application slows down considering to the first time load performance. How can i solve this situation. It has became a bottle neck for the application now. Can anyone help.

Comment: You're going to need to profile the application to find out what's going on, but it sounds like when you close a tab you're not clearing all references to the tab.  Perhaps you have a caching mechanism in place, or some event handlers wired up that are maintaining a reference - but without seeing any code, it's hard for anyone to tell.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a memory profiler to find out which parts of your code are holding on to the data. Search for '.NET memory profiler'.

Answer (score 0):

I used [EQATEC](http://eqatec.com/Profiler/) profiler to profile my custom controls in Silverlight, WPF and Windows Phone. It was really useful.